# How to structure my data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to the data structure with Firebase.

I read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

I understood that it was necessary to use a flattened structure.

But I'm not sure how to do that in real world.

And I think that to use the Firebase `rules` correctly I need a suitable structure (but I have no experience with that).

I have 2 types of data:

**A list of parts :**

```
parts: {
  part1: {
    chapter1: {
      lesson1,
      lesson2,
      ...etc
    },
     chapter2: {
      lesson1,
      lesson2,
      ...etc
    },
     chapterX: {
      ...etc
    },
  },
  part2: {
    chapter1: {
      lesson1,
      lesson2,
      ...etc
    },
     chapterX: {
      ...etc
    },
  },
  partX: {
    ...etc
  }
}
```

**And a list of users :**

```
users: {
  user1: {
    name,
    email,
    ...etc
  },
  user2: {
    name,
    email,
    ...etc
  },
  user3: {
    ...etc
  },
  etc...
}
```

- Each user can validate a lesson and its progress must be saved.
- If the user validates all the lessons: he validates the chapter.
- And if he validates all chapters: he validates the part.

**I am thinking about to structure my Firebase database like this:**

```
{
  users: {
    $uid: {
      name,
      email,
      ...
    }
  },
  checked: {
    user1: {
      parts: {
        part1: true
      },
      chapters: {
        chapter1: true,
        chapter2: true
      },
      lessons: {
        lesson1: true,
        lesson7: true,
        lesson15: true,
      }
    },
    user2: {
      parts: {
        part3: true
      },
      chapters: {
        chapter1: true
      },
      lessons: {
        lesson18: true,
        lesson57: true,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And for Firebase `rules`:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "checked": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to go?

Are the `rules` OK?

Thanks!

Comment: These rules seems like a good first step, as they allow users to only write their own data. Unless you have specific concerns about the rules, it'll be hard to say more though.

Comment: Thanks! For the moment it's all I need for the rules. I will make them evolve if the app grew up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, you are doing the right way. And the rules are OK. The structure of your database fits the way you want to read them so you are doing the right way.

Comment: Thanks! Firebase gives a lot of possibilities but it's hard to know what the best practices are. I am comforted by your answer!